Circuits for matrix multiplication over reals can be assumed bi-linear? Looking for reference/proof
In Ran Raz's paper, top of page 3, he uses the following claim without proof or reference, saying it is well-known and easy to prove:
Let $C$ be an arithmetic circuit for multiplying two matrices over the reals (or any other bi-linear function).
Then we can transform $C$ into a circuit $C'$ for multiplying two matrices such that

$C'$ is larger than $C$ by at most a universal constant factor.
Every multiplication gate in $C'$ is bi-linear: meaning it computes a product of a linear combination of the first matrix's values, with a linear combination of the second matrix's values.

Can someone write a proof or give a reference?

Bürgisser-Clausen-Shokrollahi, the beginning of Chapter 14. Specifically Strassen's Prop 14.1, through equation (14.8).
